# Updating a MySQL column that contains dot (.) in its name

Tags: php, mysql

I have columns that their names have the structure `nameUser.Name`, but I'm having trouble updating them. I've tried a few possibilities:

```
// Ideally, I'd like to do this (since the User.Name is 'dynamic', ie, it depends
// on who is logged in):
$userLogged = 'Some.User';
$columnName = 'name' . $userLogged;
mysql_query("UPDATE Industries SET '$columnName'='$name' WHERE id='$id'");
// Another try:
mysql_query("UPDATE Industries SET $columnName='$name' WHERE id='$id'");
// Alternatively, if the above cannot be achieved:
mysql_query("UPDATE Industries SET 'nameSome.User'='$name' WHERE id='$id'");
// Yet another try:
mysql_query("UPDATE Industries SET nameSome.User='$name' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Non of the above works, however. Why?

Comment: On a side note, be careful you're not ending up vulnarable to [SQL inject attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters).

Comment: For your issue, you probably need to quote the column name, the answer can probably be found at [this MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), at first glance I'd say MySQL requires backticks (or double quotes if the ANSI variant is allowed) around column names with period characters in them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of using single-quotes for the column name, use backticks (on most keyboards, to the left of the 1 key).

Like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Industries SET `nameSome.User`='$name' WHERE id='$id'");
```

Answer (score 21):

Because that is also the syntax for `database.table.column`. Youll have to quote them like

```
`nameUser.name`
```

Though really, if you created/designed the db you should never use column names like that. Its just a horrible idea.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not a programmer. However, will remember this for the future!