# insert in table with Laravel with period (speckeld)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

Good morning everybody.

I have a problem that I could not solve

I'm trying to save a record in the database with Laravel, the problem is that one of the fields has a point in its name.

This is the structure:
[struct table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwTct.png)

I tried to do this:

```
$emqu_accountavg = DB::table('emqu_accountavg_resptime')->insert([
                    'company_id' => $company_id,
                    '#Month' => $item['#Month'],
                    'System' => $item['System'],
                    'APPLID' => $item['APPLID'],
                    'GUI/NoGUI' => $item['GUI/NoGUI'],
                    'Resptime avg. (ms)' => $item['Resptime avg. (ms)'],
                ]);
```

But this is the error I get:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 647:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Resptime avg. (ms)' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `emqu_accountavg_resptime` (`company_id`, `#Month`, `System`, `APPLID`, `GUI/NoGUI`, `Resptime avg`.` (ms)`) values (1, 12017, BWP, APPL358552, GUI, 1581,4))
```

I also tried to do it this way:

```
emqu_accountavg_resptime::create([
                    'company_id' => $company_id,
                    '#Month' => $item['#Month'],
                    'System' => $item['System'],
                    'APPLID' => $item['APPLID'],
                    'GUI/NoGUI' => $item['GUI/NoGUI'],
                    'Resptime avg. (ms)' => $item['Resptime avg. (ms)'],
                ]);
```

No error occurs and the records are saved, but the one that has point keeps it null.
I check this value:

```
$item['Resptime avg. (ms)']
```

And okay, the problem is the name of that field with speckeld (point) in the database

Comment: Not sure if that will work.. Try `DB:raw('\`Resptime avg. (ms)\`') => $item['Resptime avg. (ms)']`

Answer (score 0):

You can see on your first error that the column laravel tries to insert to is `Resptime avg`.` (ms)` It should be `Resptime avg. (ms)`.

You can find how to properly escape the value here:

[Updating a MySQL column that contains dot (.) in its name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229287/updating-a-mysql-column-that-contains-dot-in-its-name)

Comment: I made this: emqu_accountavg_resptime::create([
                        'company_id' => $company_id,
                        '#Month' => $item['#Month'],
                        'System' => $item['System'],
                        'APPLID' => $item['APPLID'],
                        'GUI/NoGUI' => $item['GUI/NoGUI'],
                        `Resptime avg.(ms)` => $item['Resptime avg. (ms)'],
                    ]);  but, value is saved as null

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, without specifying the names of the fields of the table, but respecting the order of the same as it is stored, thus:

```
DB::insert('insert into emqu_accountavg_resptime values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [$company_id, $item['#Month'],$item['System'],$item['APPLID'],$item['GUI/NoGUI'],$item['Resptime avg. (ms)']]);
```

Thanks everyone for your help.