MySql field name have dot . Data not insert
I have OrderList table in mysql. there is field name paymentInfo.Prepaid.razorpayOrderId.  I want to insert the data using codeigniter. But I'm getting below the error

Unknown column 'paymentInfo.Prepaid.razorpayOrderId' in 'field list'

My Code
$data["paymentInfo.Prepaid.razorpayOrderId"] = "test";

$this->db->insert('OrderList', $data);


Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229287/updating-a-mysql-column-that-contains-dot-in-its-name

I need in codeigniter

Try $data["`paymentInfo.Prepaid.razorpayOrderId`"] = "test";

@Akina, it's not working. Already tried
